# Calling functions from inside if statement, just first one returning values

Tags: php, return

This returns valid data.

```
    if($this->empty_check()){
            $this->name(); // Valid name
            $this->email(); //Valid email
        }
```

I've two methods and they both run perfectly, however when I put them inside if statement to check if they both return true just first on is running. I tried deleting the first method($this->name()) and apparently second one started working.. but not both at same time.

This is what causes issue like I described above.

```
        if($this->name() and $this->email()){
            echo "valid data!";
        }
```

IMO it should echo Valid name, Valid email and Valid data, but only echoing Valid name.

Comment: Have you tried researching the AND operator for PHP?

Comment: And what exactly does `$this->name()` do and more specifically what does it **return**?

Comment: thanks @deceze i just realized that $this->name method was returning null because i didn't return any value except false : ) ..wow already -1 rep

Comment: yes- -1; the comunity is fast in downvoting. next time ask only if you a) already know the error you made, and b) if you have an high sofisticated problem. And - sure - dont expect to get a reason why downvoted. (sarcastic)

Comment: @halfbit So, you would say this is a great question, well researched, complete with all information required to solve it, the solution being more than what's written in the manual?

Comment: @deceze: no. I am a programmer, and good in logic: [great,well,complete] > ?? > [stupid, bad, incomplete]. its in between. And when I downvote, I take the time to explain why. And if one of my questions gets downvoted, I am happy to get told why - and just an idea ... isnt downvoting easy if someone has no reputation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running into *short-circuiting*.

Conditionals are designed to check values, not perform actions, so they are optimised such that `if (false && x)` means `x` won't be evaluated at all; it cannot change the meaning of the overarching conditional because there was already `false` on the left hand side.

Your call to `name()` must be failing, and so the call to `email()` doesn't even take place.

I would suggest *not* bundling these calls into a conditional.

```
$success  = $this->name();
$success &= $this->email();

if ($success) {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: yeah definitely a satisfying answer and yeah name method was returning false while i thought it wasn't and prolly the reason why i wrote this question. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

be careful calling functions from within IF statements (or alike)

1. threre are "side effects" called side effects ;-) to that later
2. Keep in mind, that most languages evaluate the IF clause only till it is clear if TRUE or FALSE (a very easy description), that means the second value is not evaluated if the first is already FALSE - when AND or true when OR

So in your case it looks like `$this->name()` makes the output 'valid name' but `return`s false/0 or alike.

-

to side effects

these are realy bad sometimes, so avoid them .. this example is foryou now:

```
if (++x > 2 or ++y >5) ...
```

just look at that and think about what happens when x is already 2.